# Wordpress Admin Area not Working after backup

Tags: php, wordpress

We uploaded a backup of the web site, and when we uploaded the files, we cannot access the admin area, receiving below

> There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your
> site admin email inbox for instructions.

I tried to to rename the plugin folder and checked again, but nothing fixed.

I enabled the debug and received below error

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
> callback, function 'wp_schedule_https_detection' not found or invalid
> function name in
> /home/forsahub/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 292

here is below the code of line 292 function that caused the error

```
public function apply_filters( $value, $args ) {
        if ( ! $this->callbacks ) {
            return $value;
        }

        $nesting_level = $this->nesting_level++;

        $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] = array_keys( $this->callbacks );
        $num_args                           = count( $args );

        do {
            $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] = current( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
            $priority                                 = $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ];

            foreach ( $this->callbacks[ $priority ] as $the_ ) {
                if ( ! $this->doing_action ) {
                    $args[0] = $value;
                }

                // Avoid the array_slice() if possible.
                if ( 0 == $the_['accepted_args'] ) {
                    $value = call_user_func( $the_['function'] );
                } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
                    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
                } else {
                    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
                }
            }
        } while ( false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );

        unset( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
        unset( $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] );

        $this->nesting_level--;

        return $value;
    }
```

Comment: The function didn't caused the problem - it's just where the problem hit.. Try disabling your plugins one by one and see if that helps troubleshoot the actual problem.

Comment: I tried this, and still have same issue

Comment: Try this then: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/386578/error-in-class-wp-hook-php